# Php javascript - get page title in php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to pass page title inside script using php.

```
val = document.title;
```

like below code.

```
   <script>
    "Val" : echo $val;"
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use PHP for this?

Comment: Why not just use the variable `val` as it is? Why need to use `php` to pass it in a script?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign php variables to js using following script.

```
<script>
    var val= <?php echo $val; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Yes but how can i get page title inside script

Comment: Please clarify your question what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: he wants to assign js var into php

Comment: You can assign js variable in php unless you use AJAX for that. @sukumarybroz

Comment: Yes Thamaraiselvam.. That's my exact questions

Comment: If that's you question then you have to use AJAX for the same. @sukumarybroz

Comment: Sorry - just noticed you want to convert javascript into php variable - as suggested earlier, you should probably use either ajax or websockets.

Answer (score 0):

**Assign PHP variable to js**

you just need to wrap code inside php tags
and file containing this code must be a valid php file eg. `.php`
this will not working inside `.js` file

```
<script>
  var Val =  '<?php echo $val ?>';
</script>
```

**Assign js variable to PHP**

you can make call to php file using ajax/[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourphp.php",
method: 'post',
  data: {'page_title': document.title},
  success: function(resp){
//do something
  }
});
```

in your php file

```
<?php 
 $title = $_POST['page_title'];
?>
```

Comment: he wants to assign js var into php

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = (document.title);
console.log(title);
```

or

```
var title = $(document).find("title").text();
console.log(title);
```

Here is the code to get the title and set a new title :

```
test();
function test() { 
    var pgtitle=document.title; 
    console.log(pgtitle); 
    var pgtitle='test';
    document.title = pgtitle;
};
```

Comment: i already tried like this
window.onload = function() {
pgtitle=document.title; 
console.log(pgtitle);
document.getElementById("pgtitle").value = pgtitle;
};

Comment: what do you want? You want to set page title or get page title ?